# Javascript setTimeout : Set a delay between beeps

Tags: javascript, loops, settimeout

I have done something wrong the following code is not setting the delay between executing the beeps.  It is looping 3 times as expected and beeping 3 times, but all at the same time.

It seems my interval value of 3000 is not being activated.

I am probably doing it the wrong way.  What have I misunderstood ?

```
var myBeep = new Audio('pins/beep1Sec.mp3');

var dbg = "";

function doBeeps(Start, NoOfTimes, Interval) {
    console.log(Start);
    bp = document.getElementById("beep");  // just for testing

    myBeep.play();
    console.log("Playing Beep");
    dbg += " beep : " + Start;
    bp.innerHTML = dbg;
    Start++;

    if( Start <= NoOfTimes ){
        console.log ("Start=" + Start + " ~~~ NoOfTimes=" + NoOfTimes + " ~~~ Interval=" + Interval);
        setTimeout( doBeeps(Start,NoOfTimes,Interval),Interval);
    }
}

doBeeps(1,3, 3000);
```

**MY ERROR**

Thanks for pointing me to a satisfactory answer.  My error was not making my call to itself a function in SetTimeout.  This is what it should look like

```
setTimeout( function () {doBeeps(Start,NoOfTimes,Interval)} ,Interval);
```

One day the mists of javascript internals might clear !!

Comment: Duplicate of so many "why is my setTimeout getting called immediately" questions I don't even know where to start =/

Comment: `setTimeout` takes a function and a delay.  You are passing the *result of calling a function*, and a delay.